# war-handler no longer in lib-noir?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to upgrade my Clojure web app to the latest version of lib-noir and it's failing to compile because middleware/war-handler no longer exists. If I remove "(def war-handler (middleware/war-handler app))" from my app will it still work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

war-handler was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/noir-clojure/lib-noir/commit/5c7ebf04dd8c3c93277139f0efbdeb6e9d8d0bf3#diff-af11361c49bf2213d9f70deace6f2ece) because it was deemed no longer necessary. From the cahnge it looks like you can now use `wrap-base-url` or `app-handler` to get the same effect.